# bash command prompt autocomplete by folder/filename initial?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

### In brief

Bash prompt has the autocomplete feature when we hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>.
When there are multiple outcomes, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> will display the candidate list.

I want to enter the initials of folder/filename and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete as in programming autocomplete.

### In details

For example we have folder `foods` as below

```
$ ls ./foods
apple apple-cake banana cherry
```

When we type in `ap` - hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, two folder listed i.e.

```
apple apple-cake
```

I'm looking for way to enter initials for `apple-cake` as **a c**, and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to get autocomplete as `apple-cake`

Is it possible and how to?

Comment: In default bash behaviour the short answer is no, what you're asking is not possible. You could try renaming your folders somehow (ie a-apple, ac-apple-cake) to try to do what you are asking but this might not fit with other considerations you may have for naming conventions. You can extend bash completion yourself through the `complete` command and clever use of "switches" (ie -a for apple, -ac for apple-cake, etc). [Writing your own Bash Completion Function](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html)

Comment: Zsh can do this. Consider switching. :)

Comment: @muru May you list Zsh homepage - is it www.zsh.org?

Comment: Yes, but on Ubuntu you can just do `sudo apt-get install zsh`